# Return a json on browser - Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I have this function, it returns a result on console:

```
numbers_to_add = list(range(10000001))
try:
    req = request.Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/total'
        , data=bytes(json.dumps(numbers_to_add), 'utf_8')
        , headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        , method='POST')
    result = json.loads(request.urlopen(req).read(), encoding='utf_8')
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

It returns a result on range `10000001`

Now , I want to return this on browser request, in a Flask application, I've tried this:

```
def hardCoded():
    numbers_to_add = list(range(10000001))
    try:
        req = request.Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/total'
            , data=bytes(json.dumps(numbers_to_add), 'utf_8')
            , headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            , method='POST')
        result = json.loads(request.urlopen(req).read(), encoding='utf_8')
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

class rangeNumbers(Resource):
    def get(self, range):
        return {'data': directSum.hardCoded(range)}

api.add_resource(rangeNumbers, '/range/<range>')
```

When I query this on my browser, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
File "app.py", line 16, in get
return {'data': directSum.hardCoded()}
TypeError: hardCoded() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `directSum` here? Is `hardCoded` actually a method on a class?

Comment: Hi, sorry directSum is a file where the hardCoded method is, I just put everything in here, hardCoded isn't actually on a class now that I recall... But I have another method which is working fine, without being in a class...

Comment: The most obvious error here is you're trying to pass in `range` as an argument to `hardCoded()` but it doesn't take any argument, that's why the interpreter is complaining.  If `range(10000001)` is supposed to be dynamic, pass in as a parameter instead (`def hardCoded(range):`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `range` is meant to be the `n` number to return, in this case, `10000001`, then you will want to do this instead:

In your `directSum` file:

```
def hardCoded(rng):
    numbers_to_add = list(range(rng))
    try:
    # ... rest of code ...
```

In your main file:

```
class rangeNumbers(Resource):
    def get(self, rng):
        return {'data': directSum.hardCoded(rng)}
```

Where when you call `rangeNumbers().get` you do this:

```
rng_num = rangeNumbers()
rng_num.get(10000001)
```

Notice I changed your variable `range` to `rng`.  It's in your best interest to *not* overshadow the `builtin` names even within a local scope.  Otherwise calling `range(range)` is going to give you endless pain.

Comment: Thank You very much, just a question, and excuse me, I got this api.add_resource(rangeNumbers, '/range/<range>') , where do I need to pass this rng_num variable? It says 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
'

Comment: In that case I *think* you should be calling `api.resource('/range/<range>').get(10000001)`.  I'm not too familiar with `flask`, only fiddled with it a bit so I don't know if `get()` is a default implement method.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, If I have more trouble I'll open a new question